# Virtual Directory Within Forms Authentication Secured Site Gives 401 - Unauthorized Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

When deploying updated code to our production site earlier, we found that links to static content in a virtual directory inside our web application (Asp.NET MVC based) suddenly started displaying 401 - Unauthorized errors.

No configuration changes were made during the deployment; files were updated in the web application, and the application pool recycled.[image: 401 - Unauthorized]

Answer (score 0):

The culprit ended up being that upgrading a nuget package had stripped an attribute from a node in our web.config:

```
<system.webServer>

   <modules>
     ...
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Replacing the attribute fixed the problem.

```
<system.webServer>

   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     ...
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Because the virtual directory doesn't exist in our development environment, we didn't catch the problem until we deployed to production.  Lesson learned!